# Linking opencv-python to opencv-cuda in Arch

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to to get OpenCV with CUDA to be used in Python open-cv on Arch Linux, but I'm not sure how to link it.

Arch provides a package [opencv-cuda](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/opencv-cuda/), which provides [these files](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/opencv-cuda/files/).

Guides I've found said to link the python cv2.so to the one provided, but the package doesn't provide that. My python `site_packages` has `cv2.abi3.so` in it, and I've tried linking that to `core.so` and `cvv.so` to no avail.

Do I need to build it differently to support Python? Or is there another step I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Arch, opencv-cuda **provides** `opencv=4.6.0`, but you still need the python bindings. Fortunately though, installing `python-opencv` after installling `opencv-cuda` works, since it leverages it.

I just set up my Python virtual environment to allow system site packages (`python -m venv .venv --system-site-packages`), and it works like a charm! Neural net image detection runs ~300% as fast now.

Comment: I'm sure there's *some* way to link opencv from pip to the system opencv library, but this is a lot easier anyhow.

Comment: Stop rolling back; meta commentary has no place in questions or answers.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build OpenCV with support.  I'm old school so I still build things.

> Here's a good list of [build flags](https://www.simonwenkel.com/notes/software_libraries/opencv/compiling-opencv.html#important-compilation-flags): Full cuda support can be
> enabled using the following flags:
>
> ```
> WITH_CUDA=ON
> WITH_NVCUVID=ON 
> CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON
> WITH_CUBLAS=ON
> WITH_CUFFT=ON
> OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON
> ```

Here's good how to on how to [build it.](https://www.simonwenkel.com/notes/software_libraries/opencv/compiling-opencv.html#important-compilation-flags)

Here's how to use those flags to make sure [cuda is installed](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html).

Here's a complete tutorail from begining to end on how to [enable the build for python](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-python-source-with-opencv-and-opencv-contrib-ba95d709eb) (with pictures.)

Answer (score 0):

The mods didn't like me linking to my own website, so I am pasting in the answer to your question. This is exactly how to get CUDA support for OpenCV in Arch Linux. The Arch Package and bindings don't work in most situations, even if you use the --system-site-packages. This solution works consistently.

**Step 1: Install Python 2**

Yeah, I know it’s a little weird. I have Python 3 installed and that’s what I use every day. But I couldn’t get it to compile without Python 2 being present. You can install this from the AUR; it shouldn’t affect anything you do.

First, add this key:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 04C367C218ADD4FF
Then clone the AUR

git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/python2.git && cd python2
and install it.

makepkg -si
```

You never know, it may still come in handy. On to the next part.

**Step 2: The Prerequisites**

These are a set of prerequisites for compiling OpenCV from source. Yes, I know python-opencv is in there, and we’re replacing it, but it needs to be in place to build your custom version of OpenCV. Don’t ask me why.

```
sudo pacman -S base-devel cmake git python python-numpy python-opencv openmpi python-mpi4py boost
```

**Step 4: The NVIDIA Stuff**

If you have an NVIDIA card (like I do) here is what you need to install. You may have this stuff already. Thankfully you don’t need to compile the NVIDIA stuff by hand.

```
sudo pacman -S nvidia nvidia-utils nvidia-settings cuda
```

After this, you’re just about ready to compile. Next, you have to create your CMAKE commands.

**Step 5: Figure Out What You have**

If you have an NVIDIA 4080 you can skip this section and copy my code. If not, here’s how to check which video card you’re running:

```
lspci -v | grep VGA
```

[image]

This will show you what video card you're running.

Find the video card you’re using. If it’s an NVIDIA card, you find out [which CUDA version you’re running here](https://arnon.dk/matching-sm-architectures-arch-and-gencode-for-various-nvidia-cards/).

If you don’t see your card, you may be able to [find it here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

You need to find out what version of CUDA your card supports. I have a 4080, so I needed 8.9. Which we’ll see why that’s relevant in the next section.

*Note: You’ll need to know what version of CUDA your card supports.*

**Step 6: Grab the OpenCV Repos**

Here are the two repos you will need:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

We will link the contrib folder in our CMAKE configuration.

I do all my source building in a ~/src folder. But here is the layout I have:

```
/src/opencv
/src/opencv_contrib
```

Then I create a “build” folder:

```
/src/build
```

And this is the folder I build OpenCV in. This is an “out of source build” and works well for me. You can delete everything if something doesn’t work and run CMAKE differently.

**Step 7: CMAKE flags**
Next, you need to set your CMAKE flags. Here’s the type of install I built:

OpenCV with:

- CUDA Stuff
- Some OpenCV examples
- No Docs
- No Tests
- OpenCL
- FFmpeg
- Stuff built just for my Video Card.

Here is the final CMAKE command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib  \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules  \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON  \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=8.9  \
-D ARCH=sm_89  \
-D gencode=arch=compute_89,code=sm_89  \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON  \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON  \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=ON  \
-D WITH_CUFFT=ON  \
-D WITH_NVCUVID=ON  \
-D WITH_OPENMP=ON  \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  \
-D BUILD_DOCS=OFF  \
-D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF  \
-D BUILD_TESTS=OFF  \
-D WITH_TBB=ON  \
-D WITH_IPP=ON  \
-D WITH_NVCUVID=ON  \
-D WITH_CSTRIPES=ON  \
-D WITH_OPENCL=ON  \
-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON  \
-D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib  \
-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Ofast"  \
../opencv
```

**Step 9: Build It!**

If you have everything selected and there are no errors with your CMAKE configuration, it’s time to build. Simple command:

```
make -j$(nproc)
```

then

```
sudo make install
```

Finally you need to add the new OpenCV to your Python Path:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Note, for me, it was python3.10. It may be different for you.

You’re done! To make sure it works:

Create a Python file that has this:

```
import cv2

print("OpenCV version:", cv2.__version__)
print("CUDA supported:", cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() > 0)
```

And you should see this:

[image]

And you're done.